# "No space left on device" /dev/loop0"

Tags: disk-usage

Been using Ubuntu for a couple of weeks now and have encountered a problem. I have the message "No space left on device" and after searching for a while I found that `/dev/loop0` is taking up huge space. How do I unmount/`empty /dev/loop0`?

After command: `df -h`

```
greger@ubuntu:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       12G   11G  627M  95% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           791M 1000K  790M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  388K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda4       151G   12G  139G   8% /host
```

Am I right if this command means that a lot of processes is using it?

```
greger@ubuntu:/$ fuser -m /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0:           1905  1945  1946  1960  1968  1970  1977  1989  1992  1997  2000  2002  2008  2009  2010  2013  2019  2020  2027  2029  2040  2044  2048  2051  2052  2055  2061  2069  2077  2094  2096  2098  2106  2108  2109  2139  2141  2162  2192  2201  2203  2205  2207  2209  2242  2254  2256  2276  2284  2293  2300  2316  2330  2339  2348  2438  2447  2449  2453  2572
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file: `/dev/loop0` is a special type of system file used as a virtual device so it doesn't take up any space and is used to mount image files and ISO files.

As I see, `/dev/loop0` is mounted on `/`, so I assume that this is a Wubi system and in this case something else is using your space.

This command: `df -h` is for showing you the space left and used on the virtual drive image on the physical drive. You must to use `du` command to see exactly which files are taking your space.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

I cleaned up it a little but it should be a good idea to increase the space a little? That i could do with Wubi, like this one?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk

Feels terrible when I'm so new to Ubuntu and am completely lost.