# No space left on device even after deleting files

Tags: disk-usage, delete

I used bleachbit on root and after deleting 100s of megabytes it still says there is no space left on device? What can I do to fix this? I believe this is a bug in Ubuntu and it remains unfixed! I deleted so many things and it still is not enough space even after emptying trash can! folder . REINSTALLATION OF UBUNTU IS NOT AN OPTION

```
  root@ubuntu:~# df -h
  df: `/media/bd4729a5-5939-40c7-a1f3-62c76ec30750': No such file or    directory
  df: `/media/B6A7-C601': No such file or directory
  Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/loop0         18G   18G     0 100% /
  /dev/sr0          1.1G  1.1G     0 100% /media/PS2_Live_Linux
  /dev/sda2          62G   40G   22G  65% /media/A000B2F200B2CF12_______
 gvfs-fuse-daemon   18G   18G     0 100% /root/.gvfs

    root@ubuntu:~# df -i
    df: `/media/bd4729a5-5939-40c7-a1f3-62c76ec30750': No such file or   directory
    df: `/media/B6A7-C601': No such file or directory
    Filesystem         Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/loop0        1136464 535980   600484   48% /
    /dev/sr0               20     20        0  100% /media/PS2_Live_Linux
    /dev/sda2        22756808 237834 22518974    2% /media    /A000B2F200B2CF12_______
    gvfs-fuse-daemon  1136464 535980   600484   48% /root/.gvfs
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/417655/no-space-left-on-device-dev-loop0. If you think it is a bug, file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /
du -h --max-depth=1
```

That will give you an idea of where the space is used. Go for a deeper max-depth if you want, or cd down the tree and run it again to get more info etc. It is likely that by deleting hundreds of MB all you did was free up more space to be consumed by a log file or something else. Find the source of the space usage, fix any problems that are causing the space usage etc and remove files that are using the space. At a glance bleachbits seems to focus on clearing temp files, cookies etc. I don't know that it looks through the whole directory structure.

Comment: I live in the USA so its getting late I am running it right now, but I must go to bed.