# inotify_add_watch -- failed: "No space left on device"

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, snap, boot-partition

I am facing a problem about "no space left on device" as shown in the Figure below.

[image]

I am relatively a newbie and don't know much about linux. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Checking out various blogs about my problem such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824759/failed-to-write-no-space-left-on-device) (which suggests that I should increase my drive size) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417655/no-space-left-on-device-dev-loop0) (which is quite similar to my problem) also highlights the same problem but does not specify any solution.

Can you please help any solution? Thank you so much for your attention.

PS: I have also taken screen shot of `df -h` as shown below [image]

Comment: I'm having a similar problem from qpdfview, which uses inotify to watch the current file. Mint 19 apparently sets the default to 8192, whereas Mint 18 used 524288. Easy to fix from the answer (thank you), but why would one appliczation watching one file consume 8192 watches anyway? Is there a way to check what else is using inotify for this?

Answer (score 32):

The error message doesn't actually refer to the amount of storage space, but to the amount of inotify watches that are available for a given file system (see also here: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers).

The quick solution (taken from the above website) would be to run

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Regards, Florian

Comment: Thank you so much Florian Echtler. I figured it out. The problem is in my /home directory which has been consumed 73% and Linux starts issuing error or warning if the available space is less than 28%. I deleted some files in my /home directory and now it is OK. Once again, I appreciate your efforts in clearing out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Watch Limits** are like rules that control how many folders and files you can monitor for changes using the `inotify` feature on a Linux system.

**Example:** Imagine you have a security camera system that watches your house. It uses inotify to notify you of any movement. But there's a rule that says you can only watch a maximum of 50 rooms (folders). This rule (the watch limit) stops one person from trying to watch 1,000 rooms, which would be a waste of computer resources.

So, watch limits keep things efficient and prevent anyone from using too much computer power to watch things with inotify.

We can check:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

To increase the watch limits, we need to edit configuration file `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Add this line at the end of the file:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=65536
```

Apply changes by running

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem with disc storage space. I was getting this error message while running a python script, when I had ~100 GB disc space left. There are few solutions suggested by previous users. For me, just restarting the system stopped showing this error message.

Thanks
J